# How to find all entire functions satisfying condition?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I find all the entire functions $ f $ such that $ f(1) = 10 $ and 
$ f(z) - z^3  \geq |e^z| $ for all $ z \in \mathbb{C} $?

So 
$$
\left| \frac{e^z}{f(z)-z^3} \right|  \leq 1 
$$
and this is bounded and constant by Liouville's theorem
but how do I continue from here?

Comment: If this ratio is constant, surely then you can just solve for $f$ and this gives a family of functions? Just pick the one with the condition $f(1) = 10$.

Comment: For this question to make sense you should replace $f(z)-z^{3}$ by its absolute value.